# Which visibility parameter to give structs and functions, which shall be visible in a subsubmodule?

Tags: rust, visibility

**TL;DR** I figured out, that I do not need to give any visibility to a struct of a function, if I want to make use of it in a (sub)^+-module. Respecting the level of the submodule, just write `use super::{<my-code>};` with `super::` repeating the amount of times as the level of the submodule.

Edit: I have added a small code example to better demonstrate my problem.

Every now and then I come across the architectural problem: "Is this file already too big?" Let me therefore introduce the initial code.

```rust
mod module {
    struct Parameter {}

    struct Foo{}

    fn test_foo(foo: Foo, param: Parameter) -> bool {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

To fix the problem with too large code files I restructure the file into a module and dump each self-containing set of code into a submodule. Let the following be an example for that:

```
crate
 └── module
     └── submoduleA
```

Adaption of code in any submodule is fairly easy. To make code of `mod` module visible in `mod` submoduleA, I just annotate the respective piece of code I write `use super::{<my-code>};` at the beginning of the submodule's file. The code could look like this:

```rust
mod module {
    struct Parameter {}

    mod submoduleA {
        use super::Parameter;

        struct Foo {}

        fn test_foo(foo: Foo, param: Parameter) -> bool {
            unimplemented!()
        }
    }
}
```

Now it gets spicy. What if I have to restructure a submodule? Let the following be an example for that:

```
crate
 └── module
     └── submoduleA
         └── subsubmoduleA
```

Which visibility type shall I add for a piece of code in the module's file, if I want code of module be visible at the subsubmodule level? And how to I introduce this piece of code in my subsubmodule?

The following piece of code does <s>not</s> work:

```rust
mod module {
    struct Parameter {}

    mod submoduleA {

        mod subsubmoduleA {
            use super::super::Parameter;

            struct Foo {}

            fn test_foo(foo: Foo, param: Parameter) -> bool {
                unimplemented!()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am confused. You do not need any `pub` specifier to make items in a module visible to its own submodules; that is always the case. Can you be more specific about which module is defining and which is the user?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry to bother with the question. Now I also figured out, what you meant and solved my dilemma.

Comment: Glad I could help, even by accident.